# Connecting SFM3000 with Labview

Tags: labview, i2c

I'm new in Labview an I hope that someone can help me.
I got the Sensirion Flowmeter SFM3000 and the USB Device:
http://www.sensirion.com/de/produkte/massenflussmesser-fuer-gase/evaluationskits/evaluationskit-ek-f3x/     (German)

I know that it is working with a I2C Bus, but thats totally new for me. Did someone got a vi that reads in the values of a I2C bus or maybe a vi for the SFM3000?
There is another comparable topic here, but i really dont know how to begin to get the data of the flowmeter:
[Connecting I2C Device to Labview using NI-845x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31295300/connecting-i2c-device-to-labview-using-ni-845x)

Answer (score 0):

ClaudeUntel has written vis to interface with the dongle through iowkit.dll (installed with Sensirion's software)

http://forums.ni.com/t5/LabVIEW/sensirion-ek-h5-or-Humidity-Sensor-SHT21-for-labview/td-p/1647980

Download link: http://forums.ni.com/ni/attachments/ni/170/749141/1/SHT75_IOWarrior.llb

In IOWarrior_SHT75_GetTempHumid.vi, ClaudeUntel shows how to combine his AskMeasurement and ReadMeasurement vis. For the SHT75, it sends binary 00011 for measure temperature and then a 00101 for measure humidity.

These values are documented in http://www.sensirion.com/fileadmin/user_upload/customers/sensirion/Dokumente/Humidity/Sensirion_Humidity_SHT7x_Datasheet_V5.pdf

For the SFM3000 the interface is described here:
http://www.sensirion.com/fileadmin/user_upload/customers/sensirion/Dokumente/GasFlow/Sensirion_Gas_Flow_SFM3000_I2C_Functional_Description_V1.pdf

The SHT75 takes a 8 bit command, while the SFM3000 takes a 16-bit command. IOKitWrite is used to send an 8 byte "ReportID=3" packet. The AskMeasurement vi for the SHT75 sends bytes { reportID = 3, readBack = 4, command = 00011, 0, 0, 0, 0 0} which is documented here:

The 8-byte packet is documented on page 13 here:
http://elmicro.com/files/codemercs/iowarrior_datasheet.pdf
http://www.codemercs.com/downloads/iowarrior/IowKit_V15_API.pdf

I don't see a packet format to send a 16 bit command. Based on this, I don't think there is a way to use these VIs and iowkit to send a command to the SFM3000.